# EXPO React Native - Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation-drawer, react-native-reanimated

Getting these errors when using Drawer Navigation.

[image]

Here is the complete App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';


import HomePage from './components/Pages/Home.Component';
import SearchPage from './components/Pages/Search.page';
import CardsPage from './components/Pages/Cards';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={SearchPage} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Cards" component={CardsPage} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  navbar:{
    marginBottom:'10%'
  }
});
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
  ]
  };
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "talsmandb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.16",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.4",
    "expo": "~47.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.9",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If we remove the DrawerNavigation import and change the code to tab then everything works fine.

We have cleared the cache after adding the plugin.
We have completely uninstalled and reinstalled all modules.

What silly mistake have we made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

1. n`pm i react-native-reanimated`
2. Add `plugins:['react-native-reanimated/plugin']`, below presets in '<your_app_root_folder>/babel.config.js'.
3. Add `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` to the top of '<your_app_root_folder>/App.js'.
4. Reset the cache using `npx react-native start --reset-cache`.